# Binding not working even I can hit the data PropertyChange

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I am stuck here.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="80" Header="Type" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Type,Mode=TwoWay}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
```

And

```
 public string Type
    {
        get { return this.type; }
        set
        {
            if (this.type != value)
            {
                this.type = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }
    }
```

I did set the Type value somewhere. But in the gridview, it shows as 0. What is possible cause?

**EDIT:**

I set the value in an event.

```
foreach(var item in SomeViewModel.Results)
{
     if(item.type==1)
       SomeViewModel.Type ="Something";
}
```

`SomeViewModel.Results` is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: "I did get the Type value somewhere". Um... "Somewhere"? Do you know where? If you do, would you consider telling anybody? Is there possibly any code in your project that you didn't include in your question?

Comment: @EdPlunkett, See the edit code.

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF?

Comment: @Tim, it was a wrong Tag. Deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output window, I found the Binding errors. The property is not existing. I just realized that the property must be an element of ItemsSource.

I can't create my own.